# How do I render an Orchard CMS Custom Form in a modal jquery dialog

Tags: forms, modal-dialog, orchardcms

I have looked and found nothing on this subject. It must be a common requirement though. I am assuming that if I could deduce the route to my form then I could call it into a modal via a jquery click action on a class.

I can render a whole page (i.e. with header, footer and navigation) in this fashion - but I just want the actual form part to load in the dialog not the whole page.

I am new to Orchard - though so far impressed aside from this stumbling block.

Answer (score 2):

Because Orchard is an MVC, all content (widgets, or regular pages, etc.) on the page has their views. You can override any of this views by making an [Alternate](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Customizing-Orchard-using-Designer-Helper-Tools). And it's really simple using [Designer Tools](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Orchard.DesignerTools).
Hope it helps.